# Javascript - returning concatenates instead of sum of variables from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am trying to get values from input field using `.each()` and adding them to show the sum in another input value. But unfortunately in spite of using parseInt() I am unable to get sum.

**HTML**

```
<input type=text name=value[] id=value class="value">
<input type=text name=value[] id=value class="value">
<input type=text name=totalvalue id=totalvalue>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var totalvalue = parseInt(0);
$(document).on("focusout",".value",function() {
    $(".value").each(function() {
        totalvalue = parseInt(totalvalue + $(this).val());
    });
    $("#totalvalue").val(totalvalue);
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pr4n8b2u/)

Comment: you need to parseInt every string ... `$(this).val()` is a string ... `parseInt($(this).val())` is a Number

Comment: Oh thank you. Kindly post that as an answer so that I can select it as the solution. Thank you so much for the prompt reply

Comment: let someone else have the points :p

Comment: its because they are string that you are trying to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're parsing line is saying is

> Add the `totalValue` to the string from the input, then parse the result.

Which is why it's concatenating. Instead, you need to add the `totalValue` *outside* of the `parseInt()` so that it's saying

> Take the take the `totalValue` and add the parsed input value to it.

Like this

```
totalvalue = totalvalue + parseInt($(this).val());
```

This can be further shortened to

```
totalvalue += parseInt($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `totalvalue` inside focusout function  ,because it will always show the total of two input text and pass the input value empty state when sum !!!

```
$(document).on("focusout",".value",function() {
    var totalvalue = 0;
    $(".value").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "") return;
        totalvalue +=  parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#totalvalue").val(totalvalue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`parseFloat()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiUv6fZ-vPUAhVJJ1AKHX3kBkgQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FparseFloat&usg=AFQjCNFGjOkpZ1cWnWNYHgjw0eQjZTiL0g) on input value

```
parseFloat($(this).val()));
```

```js
var totalvalue = parseInt(0);
$(document).on("focusout",".value",function() {
    $(".value").each(function() {
        totalvalue = (totalvalue + parseFloat($(this).val()));
    });
    $("#totalvalue").val(totalvalue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text name=value[] id=value class="value">
<input type=text name=totalvalue id=totalvalue>
```

Answer (score 0):

your appending String. `$(this).val()` is a string . just parse it to int or float.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is this according to your code then it will always sum up with first box value.

```
  var value = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(value)
    totalvalue = totalvalue + value;
});
```

Otherwise you should elaborate your question so that proper answer could be provided.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a NaN data type to an Number data type. So you need to restrict it before you perform your addition operation.

Please check this one

```
var totalvalue = 0;
$(document).on("focusout",".value",function() {
    $(".value").each(function() {
        if(isNaN($(this).val()) || $(this).val() != ''){
            totalvalue = totalvalue + parseInt($(this).val());
      }
  });
  $("#totalvalue").val(totalvalue);

});
```